# Reverse a character array without changing value of number?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have for example a string (mathematical equation in postfix notation) that looks like this: The numbers are 5.33,5.32,6.33,3.22

```
5.335.32*6.333.22++
```

I'm looking to make it into prefix notation but simply reversing the string won't work due to the fact it has to retain the value of the number.

I've thought of doing a normal character by character swap in a for loop, and when encountering a digit make that into a substring and place it on afterwards but I haven't gotten it to work properly and now I'm stuck.

My end-goal is to make a binary expression tree out of that, so if there's an easier way than doing this also please let me know.

Comment: first, `5.335.32` need separator like as `5.33 5.32`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY all integers in this case will be in 0.00 format, would this change anything?

Comment: I see. But I think it requires extra effort.

Comment: If it has a decimal point, it's not an integer :) But can you assure that all numbers, without exception, will have that format?

Comment: @AntonH Yes, all will have a length of 4 (in #.## format)

Comment: Is there no `10.55` (length is 5)?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no, all numbers HAVE to be in the #.## form

Comment: It is virtually useless.

Answer (score 1):

A stack-based approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *postfix_to_prefix(const char *string) {

    char operator, *stack[1024];
    int s = 0, number, fraction;
    const char *tokens = string;

    while (1) {
        if (sscanf(tokens, "%1d.%2d", &number, &fraction) == 2) {
            stack[s] = malloc(sizeof("1.00"));
            (void) sprintf(stack[s++], "%4.2f", number + (fraction / 100.0));
            tokens += strlen("1.00");
        } else if (sscanf(tokens, "%c", &operator) == 1) {
            char *operand1 = stack[--s];
            char *operand2 = stack[--s];
            stack[s] = malloc(strlen(operand1) + strlen(operand1) + sizeof(operator) + sizeof('\0'));
            (void) sprintf(stack[s++], "%c%s%s", operator, operand1, operand2);
            free(operand1);
            free(operand2);
            tokens += sizeof(operator);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return stack[--s];
}

int main() {

    const char *string = "5.335.32*6.333.22++";

    printf("%s\n", string);

    char *inverted = postfix_to_prefix(string);

    printf("%s\n", inverted);

    free(inverted);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
> ./a.out
5.335.32*6.333.22++
++3.226.33*5.325.33
>
```

This is a bare bones implementation with no real error checking nor other finishing touches.  You'll want to check that non-communitive operations like subtraction and division come out with the operands in the correct order and reverse them if not.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char exp[] = "5.335.32*6.333.22++";
    size_t len = strlen(exp);
    char temp[len];
    char *p = temp;

    for(int i = len-1; i >= 0; ){
        if(isdigit(exp[i])){
            memcpy(p, &exp[i-4+1], 4);//all number have a length of 4 
            p += 4;
            i -= 4;
        } else {
            *p++ = exp[i--];//length of op is 1
        }
    }
    memcpy(exp, temp, len);//Write back
    puts(exp);//++3.226.33*5.325.33
    return 0;
}
```